# Debugging .net at runtime?

Tags: .net, debugging

Is there a tool which can debug my program at RUNTIME ? ( like ildasm / reflector) in runtime.

(vs doesnt help me much here)

**I need to see the CIL in runtime**

Comment: Debugging can be done only at RUNTIME. Can you describe exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BalaR I need to see the cil code in run time.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Why won't Visual Studio work for you? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) version 2 onwards does this.

Just grab the latest copy from the build server.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [windbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) - it will not be interactive *during* runtime, but you can cause a memory dump when you need and use windbg to query it.

Comment: thanks oded. 9 min. I just needed a tool to see at runtime the cil code.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Don't thank me yet... windbg takes a good time to learn to use (I have _no_ idea how to use it properly).